# Moving the video object

Tags: actionscript-3, video, actionscript, zooming, drag

I am using Actionscript. I have a video object on stage using the code below. What I would like to do is when a user hovers the mouse cursor on the border of the video object the user can drag the video object out to increase its size and zoom in or Vice Versa.

I cannot find any examples how to do this. If anyone knows Actionscript 3 I appreciate if you can help me thanks.

```
 var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
 cam.setMode(350,250,15);
 cam.setQuality(0, 85);

 cam.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandler);

 var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
 mic.gain = 50;
 mic.rate = 11;
 mic.setSilenceLevel(0, 2000);

 mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, micStatus);

 var vid:Video = new Video();
 vid.width = cam.width;
 vid.height = cam.height;
 vid.x = 15;
 vid.y =30;

 vid.attachCamera(cam);
 addChild(vid);
```

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dynamic-video-player-with-actionscript-3-part-1-of-3--active-2931

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
    vid.addEventListener(MOUSECLICK, function1)

    function1
     {
        removeEventListener(MOUSECLICK, function1) 
        stage.addEventListener(MOUSE_MOVE, function2)
     }

    function2
     {
       vid.addEventListener(MOUSECLICK, function3)
       vid.change_scale
     }

    function3
     {
       vid.removeEventListener(MOUSECLICK, function3)
       stage.removeEventListener(MOUSE_MOVE, function2)
     }
```

The rest is easy - just use good code.

Comment: Sorry to say it, Craig, but your answer does not provide and actual answer to the question, it just said 'do the scaling here', and that's exactly what he's asking for..

Comment: We have a difference of philosophy about this. To help someone learn I think it's better to give a strategic direction, instead of a complete answer that requires no further thought. Its like teaching someone to fish instead of handing him a fish. If you don't work, you don't learn programming. 
 
The help I tried to give is to add the IDEA that was missing in the OP's code -- that you need to first CLICK on the object to tell it that it can now respond to a MOUSE_MOVE. It seemed like he needed a strategy more than he needs someone to write his code for him.

Comment: I truly understand you, but I think it's better to give detail information about the problem, because it's clearly stated he need the scaling part. You haven't provided any strategic directions on that one, so his question is absolutely unanswered. And I also think that providing full and meaningful answer with a lot of detailed comments about what's going on is better than just giving directions. It's best to give example with explanation than just explanation, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use some kind of a "border" element as you said - a simple Sprite that hovers the video. You can either make it with some color, or use transparent if you want to - there's no difference. You can even make a "draggable" symbol. Then use this code:

```
var draggable:Sprite = new Sprite();
draggable.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0); // transparent
draggable.drawRect(vid.x, vid.y, vid.width, vid.height); // adjust it to fit your video
draggable.endFill();

draggable.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
draggable.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
draggable.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);

private var _dragging:Boolean;
private var _initialSize:Rectangle;
private var _initialMouse:Point;

private function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void { // begin dragging
    // get initial coordinates and dimension
    _initialSize = new Rectangle(vid.x, vid.x, vid.width, vid.height);
    // get the initial point where the mouse is
    // to calculate the difference and so adjust the width/height of the vid
    _initialMouse = new Point(e.mouseX, e.mouseY);

    _dragging = true;
}

private function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void { // dragging stopped
    _dragging = false;
}

private function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (!_dragging) // no drag, no scale
        return;

    // calculate the difference between the starting X position of the mouse
    // and the current X position of the mouse. then add this difference
    // to the initial width
    // example: if initial width was 100, and initial mouse was clicked at 50
    // after a few frames the current mouse x (e.mouseX) would be 70
    // and the calc would be: 100 + (70 - 50) = 120;
    vid.width = _initialSize.width + (e.mouseX - _initialMouse.x);

    // adjust the size of the draggable element also,
    // so you can have it the same size and click it next time properly
    // if you use a "draggable" type of button at the bottom of the video
    // then adjust the position, not the size
    draggable.width = vid.width;


    // do the same on y axis :)
    // or if you want to preserve the aspect ration, you need to calculate it
    // using the _initialSize variable. I'll leave this to you so you can
    // put some effort and feel great when you achieve your goal :)
    // just calculate the percentage difference from the width (divide)
    // and then multiply the height with the same factor.. Good luck!
}
```

It's important to know that as long as this code should work, there might be some errors as I'm writing it here and never compiled, sorry for that :)